# How to access tables from two databases in one ADF Script?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, script-task

I have two databases Employee and Employee_Archive, each one has a table 'dbo.Employee'.

I was planning to **delete Employee.dbo.Employee** if the records **already in Employee_Archive.dbo.Employee.**

I tried to use Script activity, I also tried to create a sproc to do the delete, but looks like these two databases were not linked.

```
DELETE e 
FROM [dbo].[Employee] e 
JOIN Employee_Archive.[dbo].[Employee] d 
    on e.EmployeeId = d.EmployeeId
```

Could any please tell me how to make this come true. I think it's not hard, but I'm new to the ADF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which database are you using?
In case if it is sql server, you can create linked server between those 2 and cross query the database. In case if it is Azure sql database, you can use elastic query to cross query database.

Based on the above scope, you can use a script task in the main database and execute your query.

The other way would be to use dataflow within adf wherein you can use 2 sources and get the distinct list of employees that are common and need to be deleted

Comment: Reference: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D9i7qf1vczUw&ved=2ahUKEwiOlbWLv4mFAxUpSGwGHZK3AFQQjjh6BAgPEAE&usg=AOvVaw2PMzsPg0bVjQ00MeftSYYX

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am using Azure SQL Server, and I will try both script task and data flow as you mentioned, just to practice. Thanks again!